# Unable to start new ionic project

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

Hi i have installed ionic through command `npm install -g cordova ionic`
and when I start my ionic project it gives the error. I am stuck please help me solving this error.

> Unable to add plugins. Perhaps your version of Cordova is too old. Try updating (npm install -g cordova), removing this project folder, and trying again. (CLI v1.7.11)

Your system information:

> Cordova CLI: Not installed
>
> Ionic Version: 1.1.1
>
> Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.11
>
> Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
>
> OS: Node Version: v5.1.1

[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnX8L.png)

Answer (score 2):

Cordova seems not to be installed as it says `Cordova CLI: Not installed`. Re-install it.

`npm install -g cordova`

Check if it is installed by executing:

`npm cordova -version`

Comment: I have just checked cordova version 

C:\Users\Muhammad>cordova -version
5.4.1

Answer (score 1):

Question Solved:

I solve this problem by uninstalling all previous versions of

> Cordova and ionic through command `npm uninstall -g cordova` and `npm uninstall ionic`

After that goto

> C:\Users\Muhammad and then delete the folders from with the name 
>   .ionic and 
>   .corodova

After that again open cmd and write commands `npm install -g cordova` which will install Cordova and after installing Cordova restart/logoff your Pc then again goto cmd and install ionic by typing `npm install -g ionic`

And after that create new project it will work fine. Don't forget to delete those folders otherwise it will generate same error.